# push and pull technologies using Ajax or Socket

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a website that needs to send notifications to the online clients at real time same as Facebook, after more googling, I found a lot of documentation about push and pull technology. I found from this documentation ways for implementing them using Ajax or Sockets. I need to know what is the best to use in my case and how is it coded using javascript or jquery and php.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot say you what's the best use in your case without knowing your case in detail.

In most cases it is enough to have the clients check with the server every one or two seconds, asking if something new has happened. I prefer this over sockets most of the time because it works on every web server without any configuration changes and in any browser supporting AJAX, even old ones.

If you have few clients (because every client requires an open socket on the server) and you want real realtime, you can use websockets. There are several PHP implementations, for example this one: http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/

Comment: my case is same as Facebook and Stackoverflow, when you answered my question it sent my notification, i need to do something like this, and my website expected to have many users not few.

Comment: If you have "unlimited server power" like Facebook, I would choose the sockets with an alternative solution for older browsers.
If you don't, is a delay of a second or less (you can also check for updates every 250ms if you want to) really significant to your users? If so, choose sockets. If not, choose periodically AJAX requests.

Answer (score 2):

If you can ensure that there will be only single browser open per logged in user then you can apply this long polling technique easily.

Policy for Ajax Call:

1. Do not make request every 2 seconds.
2. But wait and make request only after 2 seconds of getting response from previous request.
3. If a request does not respond within 12 seconds then do not wait send a fresh request. This is connection lost case.

Policy for server response:

1. if there is update response immediately. to check if there is update rely on session ; (better if you could send some hint from client side like latest message received; this second update checking mechanism will eliminate the restriction of single browser open as mentioned above)
2. otherwise sleep() for 1 second; (do not use infinite loop but use sleep) and then check whether there is update; if update is there respond; if not sleep again for 1 second; repeat this until total 10 seconds has elapsed and then respond back with no update

If you apply this policy (commonly known as long polling), you will find processor usage reduced from 95% to 4% under heavy load case.

Hope this explains. Best of luck.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but there is another problem fired that's how can i check for updates, the procedure i use is each user has a page in my website; when the user add,remove or update his page i must send notifications to the page followers. I have a table in my database for saving notifications.
as you say, to get updates i need to access the database each 1 sec into the server side to check if there are updates or not. are there another way to get updates without accessing the database?

Comment: you can try shared memory with file lock. but i hope you do not require that as most of the time you are sleeping in server side and only awake for few nano seconds to execute your query. your TCP handshake takes more time than PHP processing that is why we use this long polling technique which waits long between each handshake (syn-fin).

Comment: are accessing database each 1 sec represent a heavy load in the database? assume there are 1000 user that's mean 1000 database access/second

Comment: in that case you can use php shared memory with file lock to implement a kind of cache in php. basically storing recently updated ids of users with time stamps in the form of serialized array in shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

Just use apply the long-polling technique using jQuery.

Sockets are not yet supported everywhere and also you would need to open a listening socket on the server for this to work.

Comment: are long-pooling supports real-time. how it can be implemented?